# Inheritance from multiply inherited templated class ambiguity problem

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++03

I'm using Arm Compiler 5 (C++2003).

I have a problem which I couldn't name it, I currently call it multiply inherited templated mixing class ambiguity problem.

I have a very base class template `CMessageContent` which is defined as:

```
template <typename T>
class CMessageContent
{
public:
    T* GetContent();
};
```

I have an inherited class from the class above:

```
class CGarageStatus : public CMessageContent<S_GARAGE_STATUS>
{};
```

And I have another Mixing class definition which is

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class CBinaryMixableContent : public T1, public T2
{};
```

And at last, I have the class I'm dealing with.I want to  make getter setter methods targeting the class `CMessageContent<S_GARDEN_STATUS>`

```
class CHomeStatus : public CBinaryMixableContent<CGarageStatus, CMessageContent<S_GARDEN_STATUS> >
{
public:    
    void MyFoo()
    {
        CMessageContent<S_GARDEN_STATUS>::GetContent(); // A call to CMessageContent's method, but this method exist in both CGarageStatus and CMessageContent<S_GARDEN_STATUS>
    }
};
```

I can compile my app and it works but  the `CMessageContent< S_GARDEN_STATUS >::GetContent();` line in `MyFoo` method gives a warning:

```
CMessageContent<T>::GetContent [with T=S_GARAGE_STATUS] is ambiguous
```

I think I explicitly make it clear for compiler to use the GetContent method of `CMessageContent<S_GARDEN_STATUS>` class, but it seems I'm missing something. What is it? Why it still says it is ambiguous?

I tried solutions given for problems similar to mine:

```
using  CMessageContent< S_GARAGE_STATUS>::GetContent;

using this->CMessageContent< S_GARDEN_STATUS >::GetContent();
```

but couldn't managed to make warnings disappear.

The error I get when I use:

```
using  CMessageContent< S_GARAGE_STATUS>::GetContent
```

in the definition of CHomeStatus is:

```
class member designated by a using-declaration must be visible in a direct base class
```

But if I use `using CGarageStatus::GetContent`, it doesn't give warning.

Comment: Your problem is named "diamond problem". www.freecodecamp.org/news/multiple-inheritance-in-c-and-the-diamond-problem-7c12a9ddbbec/

Comment: You are practically inheriting from the same class twice. As @Caduchon said this creates a "diamond" problem, which is either avoided, or resolved by using virtual inheritance from one of the inheritance branches of the same class.

Comment: "C++2003". Well it's a horrible language, luckily it has been replaced by modern C++ :)

Comment: Okey, two mini questions. Doesnt two of the base classes are different(because different template params are given), is it still diamond problem?

Comment: If `S_GARDEN_STATUS` and `S_GARAGE_STATUS` are two different types (impossible to say, since their definitions are not in the question), then `CMessageContent<S_GARDEN_STATUS>` and `CMessageContent<S_GARAGE_STATUS>` are two different classes. If `CBinaryMixableContent` is a typo for `CMixableClass` there is no ambiguity, and any compiler that refuses to compile that code does not conform to the language definition. But there are so many gaps in the code in the question that it's really not possible to give a meaningful answer to the question.

Comment: I 'll add more explaination when im at home, but yes they are 2 different classes and CMixableClass would be CBinaryMixableContent. Code compiles but I cant get rid of ambiguos warnings

Comment: be careful with shadowing methods. if you are going to use the same method for two different classes, that will concur in realize a mixin, then you probably want to make it virtual. if that is not the case, then I would advise against having the same method name.